# scrolling in LibreOffice Calc feels like it never ends, even though I might not be reaching the last cell.?

Tags: libreoffice, scrolling

I'm having a weird scrolling issue in the new LibreOffice Calc.  Whenever I try to scroll through the cells, it just keeps going like it's never going to stop, even though I'm nowhere near the last row or column.

Has anyone else encountered this?  Is there a fix I'm missing?

Here's some additional info that might be helpful:

```
My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1
I'm using LibreOffice version 24.2
The scrolling seems to be uncontrollable in one direction
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Siddique, welcome to your first question! LibreOffice comes in two types of versions:

    Time-based release (like your version 24.2)
    Stable release (for example, version 7.6)

As explained in the [Wiki Release Plan](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleasePlan), time-based releases follow a schedule regardless of features or bugs, while stable releases offer a more reliable version with resolved issues. I recommend using the stable release for a ready-to-use LibreOffice with bug fixes.